# Service Fabric, gracefully shutdown "old" service instances

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have quite a few ASP.NET API solutions which run inside Service Fabric.

On Application Upgrade (or VM load balancing or service down scaling, ...) I want to **make sure no data is being lost**, which basically means any 1.0.0 service instances need to finish all of their still running requests before they can be deleted. In the meantime it is perfectly ok to spawn any new 1.0.1 instances.

**Is there any way SF can handle this type of scenario?**

I couldn't make any sense of the reliable service lifecycle information provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle). Also it's not feasible to handle the CancellationToken outside of my requests. Also I do not want to cancel any requests... I want all of them to complete.

Comment: I added a Task.Delay() with 10s OnCloseAsync(). Of course that's nowhere near perfect but at least it offers a higher chance of currently active requests to complete gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Service fabric upgrade services instances\replicas on a RollingUpgrade approach, that means, if you have multiple instances, it will tear down one Upgrade Domain at time, so it won't make much difference, because other instances would still receive requests until all instances\replicas get updated.

The approach you've created is not much effective as well, because the 10s delay will prevent you interrupting requests being processed but won't prevent you receiving new ones that will be likely be interrupted.

To avoid receiving new requests on instances being updated, you could pass the cancellation token to ASP.NET and create a middleware that check if the node is being shutdown and reject any new requests, then your delay might take effect if requests does not take longer than the delay.

If your concern is not interrupting requests being processed, the only way to do it effectively is tracking these requests and wait for then to finish before shutting down the the service, this is an ASP.NET limitation, not much can be done.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case. In the documentation it says the listeners are closed first. Only after that `OnCloseAsync()` is being called. My assumption is you don't receive any new messages `OnCloseAsync()`.
I did not load test this behavior yet.

Comment: it does call `OnCloseAsync()` on per UD basis, that means, one Upgrade Domain will shutdown at time, so, other instances will continue receiving work and the one being shutdown can close the endpoint to stop receiving any new calls, but does not mean that it won't kill any in flight request after the 10seconds wait time you've set in the delay, in a high load, you might get request being processed or enqueued and also some requests might take more than 10s in case of network issues or other dependencies slowness.

Comment: I am aware of that and I welcome any real solutions.